# htaccess rewrite if url extention is .php remove it

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I also want to 301 redirect any url that ends in `.php`. Then I internally redirect anything that ends in a `/` to the name before `/` plus `.php`. These both work fine when they are alone. But putting them in the same `.htaccess` I get a `The page isn't redirecting properly`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These rules should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file/ to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This does work, thank you. Do you know how to force the trailing slash too it it isn't there when typed into the address bar?